# Моя реализация пользовательского меню. Адекватен ли такой код?)

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода, рекурсия, проектирование, меню

Причина по которой я сделал так, это возможность в перспективе легко добавлять вложенные друг в друга пункты меню, тем самым разбивая функционал программы по категориям. Это моя первая программа, пишу для себя. У меня все работает нормально. Меня беспокоит вот что. Хотелось бы сделать **правильно**. Многоуровневое меню есть почти в любой игре, почти во всех программах, папки виндоус и линукс реализуют неограниченную вложенность. Но я не нашел нигде как это правильно реализовать. Написал сам.

Итак.. Есть `class Menu` объекты этого класса и будут пунктами меню. Одно  из полей этого класса содержит массив указателей на такие же объекты `Menu **pItem`. Очевидные поля и методы описывать не буду. Есть также поле `MenuType type`. Это переменная `enum`, где `{A,B,C...}`. Она отвечает за тип пункта меню. Тип отвечает за пользовательский интерфейс внутри различных пунктов меню. Позднее будет понятно. Далее в `main()` это все собирается:

```
//Инициализация объектов
MySpace::Menu main("Программа учета финансов", MySpace::A);
/************************************/
MySpace::Menu debit("Мои доходы", MySpace::B);

/************************************/
MySpace::Menu expendthings("Мои Расходы", MySpace::C);

/************************************/
MySpace::Menu creditanalis("Отчеты о расходах", MySpace::D);
MySpace::Menu creditday("Расходы за день", MySpace::E);
MySpace::Menu creditweek("Расходы за неделю", MySpace::F);
//и в таком духе
```

Затем они помещаются друг в друга:

```
main.add_Item(&debit, 1); //второй параметр это нумерация
/************************************/
main.add_Item(&expendthings, 2);

/************************************/
main.add_Item(&creditanalis, 3);
creditanalis.add_Item(&creditday, 1);
creditanalis.add_Item(&creditweek, 2);
creditanalis.add_Item(&creditmonth, 3);
//и так далее..
```

А дальше вызывается функция вызова меню для первого объекта

```
show_Menu(&main,/*другие параметры*/)
```

В ней сама реализация:

```
void show_Menu(MySpace::Menu *object, int& depthM /*и еще много чего*/)
{
/*Здесь куча всяких параметров*/
depthM++;
char answerKey = 'a';
int answerNumb = 0;
.......
do
{
    switch (object->get_Type())
    {
    case MySpace::A: //////////////////////////////// A - Main menu
        system("cls"); //Очистка экрана
        object->main_Screen(); //Вывод текущего меню на экран
        show_Advance_Main_Menu(); //Вывод значений кнопок управления
        IntOrChar(answerNumb, answerKey);//Ввод от пользователя. Возвращает по ссылке
                                         //либо цифру, либо введенный символ и цифру 0

        if (answerNumb != 0) //Если юзер ввел не цифру, то IntOrChar вернет 0
        {
            if (answerNumb > 0 && answerNumb < object->get_Size())
            {
                if (object->get_pItem((answerNumb - 1)) != nullptr)
                {
        //Здесь рекурсивно снова вызывается show_Menu() но уже с вложенным пунктом меню
                    show_Menu(object->get_pItem((answerNumb - 1))/*и еще много чего*/);
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "Не существующий пункт меню" << std::endl;
                }

            }
        }
        switch (answerKey)
        {
            /*Здесь блок управления: "Выход", "Вернуться назад", "Переименовать" и т. д.
            Для каждого типа меню реализован по-своему
            Можно вообще в отдельную функцию вынести*/
        }
        break;

    case MySpace::B: //////////////////////////////// B - Incom category list

        /*Здесь пользовательский интерфейс для типа меню B*/

        break;

    case MySpace::C: //////////////////////////////// C - Expend category list

        /*Здесь пользовательский интерфейс для типа меню С*/

        break;
    //И так далее для всех типов
    default: return;
    }

} while (true);
```

Плюс такой схемы в том, что не нужно заморачиваться с навигацией по вновь добавленным вложенным пунктам. Достаточно создать объект и вложить в другой. Минус в том что приходится рекурсивно передавать много параметров через функцию `show_Menu()`: структуры данных, флаги меню и т. д. Это выглядит странно, потому закрались сомнения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли другое решение? И скиньте ссылку, если уже видели где-то лучший вариант.

Comment: Думаю, надо уточнить вопрос. Проблема в том, что очень много параметров передается рекурсивно. Мне нужно передать кучу списков данных : категории доходов и расходов, статьи доходов, расходов еще и параметры меню. Подскажите как это можно исправить. Может все структуры данных запихнуть в один класс? И параметры в отдельный класс? Или такая реализация меню в принципе бесперспективна? Получается весь код у меня зависит от интерфейса. Как это обычно делается у нормальных людей?) Что гуглить? Спасибо.

Comment: а почему просто не писать класс?...

Comment: Извините, не понял. Класс для чего именно?

Comment: класс учетов, отчетов

Comment: Вы про типы пунктов меню говорите? Типа распихать функционал по классам, унаследовать от одного интерфейса и переопределить функционал каждого пункта в каждом отдельном классе? В мейне реализовать рекурсию используя полиморфизм с обращением к объектам через интерфейс? Так что-ли? Каждый пункт меню - отдельный класс?